# Does anyone have a working sample of implicit messages internationalization for Play Framework 2.5 Scala?

Tags: scala, internationalization, implicit, message, playframework-2.5

I have just started learning Scala, reading Play for Scala book by Manning right now.
However, I am stuck at the internationalization process, I keep getting the error:
Could not find implicit value for parameter messages, this is probably due to the fact that the book was written for earlier version of Play.

I have followed all the suggestions to migrate to 2.4/2.5, but still having the same problem for the past 2 days.

Can anyone help me create a simple program to illustrate this part of Play?
I am using Play 2.5 using Eclipse, sbt, Scala IDE and Activator

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, finally found the answer. To those who are stuck at the same questions, make sure you have

"with I18nSupport" at the end of the class definition in the controllers:

class Application @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport